# PEP343 'with' context manager and django

Tags: python, django, with-statement, contextmanager

I am doing some application testing with django frame work , 
i have a case where i test if inactive users can login , and i do like so

```
self.testuser.is_active = False
//DO testing
self.testuser.is_active = True
//Proceed
```

my question is , 
by using with context manager provided by [PEP343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)
i tried to do this but i failed

```
with self.testuser.is_active = False :
//code
```

then i tried to do

```
with self.settings(self.__set_attr(self.testuser.is_active = False)):
//code
```

it also fails

is there is a way around this ? or do i have to define a function that sets is_active to false?

Comment: the object used in with statement has to support context manager protocol, for example file object supports context manager protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is is a more generic context manager built from contextlib.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def temporary_changed_attr(object, attr, value):
    if hasattr(object, attr):
        old = getattr(object, attr)
        setattr(object, attr, value)
        yield
        setattr(object, attr, old)
    else:
        setattr(object, attr, value)
        yield
        delattr(object, attr)

# Example usage
with temporary_changed_attr(self.testuser, 'is_active', False):
    # self.testuser.is_active will be false in here
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to write your own context manager.  Here's one for your case (using [contextlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html)):

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def toggle_active_user(user):
    user.is_active = False
    yield
    user.is_active = True

with toggle_active_user(self.testuser):
    // Do testing
```

Even better, would be to save the state prior and then restore:

```
import contextlib
@contextlib.contextmanager
def toggle_active_user(user, new_value):
    previous_is_active = user.is_active
    user.is_active = new_value
    yield
    user.is_active = previous_is_active

with toggle_active_user(self.testuser, False):
    // Do testing
```

Comment: i did something like this 
        class notActive:
            def __init__(self,val):
                self.test = val
                
            def __enter__(self):
                self.test.is_active = False
                
            def __exit__(self, ty, value, tb):
                self.test.is_active = True

but your code seems more practical to me , thank you

Comment: Yeah, I just used the `contextmanager` decorator to save some of the class based scaffolding, but you've got it.